Excel Ribbon comboBox: How to set up an onChange Callback
Setting up a comboBox in a custom Ribbon.
Don't understand, how to build the onChange Callback.
This is the comboBox XML:
<group id="GroupDemo2" 
    label="SelectSheet"
    autoScale="true"
    imageMso="AddInManager">
    <comboBox id="ComboBox001"
        label="comboBox001”
        sizeString=“XXXX”
        onChange="RibbonCallbacks.ComboBox001OnChange"
        getText="RibbonCallbacks.ComboBox001GetText">
        <item id="ItemOne”
            label=“One”/>
        <item id="ItemTwo”
            label=“Two”/>
        <item id="ItemThree”
            label=“Three”/>
    </comboBox>
</group>     

I tried this, but it doesn't do anything:
Sub ComboBox001OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, id As String)
    Select Case id
        Case "ItemOne”
            Sheets("Sheet1”).Select
        Case "ItemTwo”
            Sheets("Sheet2”).Select
        Case "ItemThree”
            Sheets("Sheet3”).Select
    End Select
End Sub

Thanks!


Replace fullwidth double quote (Unicode) with halfwidth char in XLM and VBA code.

Halfwidth and fullwidth forms

The name of callback Sub should be ComboBox001_OnChange, a underscore is missing.

The return value id is One instead of ItemOne.


-- XML
<group id="GroupDemo2" 
    label="SelectSheet"
    imageMso="AddInManager">    
    <comboBox id="ComboBox001"
        label="comboBox001"
        onChange="ComboBox001_OnChange">
        <item id="ItemOne"
            label="One"/>
        <item id="ItemTwo"
            label="Two"/>
        <item id="ItemThree"
            label="Three"/>
    </comboBox>
</group>   

-- Callback VBA Code 
Sub ComboBox001_OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, id As String)
    Select Case id
        Case "One"
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Case "Two"
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Case "Three"
            Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    End Select
End Sub


There was a problem with your quote,They didn't validate, After fixing the quote now it's validate and it looks like it's going to work.
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="Contoso" insertAfterMso="TabHome">
                <group id="GroupDemo2" 
                label="SelectSheet"
                autoScale="true"
                imageMso="AddInManager">
                    <comboBox id="ComboBox001"
                    label="comboBox001"
                    sizeString="XXXX"
                    onChange="RibbonCallbacks.ComboBox001OnChange"
                    getText="RibbonCallbacks.ComboBox001GetText">
                        <item id="ItemOne"
                        label="One"/>
                        <item id="ItemTwo"
                        label="Two"/>
                        <item id="ItemThree"
                        label="Three"/>
                    </comboBox>
                </group>     
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>

About the second sub . Check Microsoft doc for combobox in the ribbon search for getText and decide if you need it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncombobox?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#events

Hi xShen. Thank you for the code. The ribbon loads and works without any issues. The problem is the Callback. This: ComboBox001OnChange does not work. I get the error "Variable not defined".
